# Adjunct matrix of a nonnegative irreducible matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**The setup.**
Let $A = ||a_{i j}||_1^n$ be nonnegative irreducible matrix (primitive if needed) which maximum eigenvalue is $r$ ($r \leq 1$). Let's consider determinant $\Delta(\lambda) = |\lambda E - A|$ and the adjoint matrix $B(\lambda) = ||b_{i j}(\lambda)||_1^n$, where $b_{i j}(\lambda)$ is an algebraic adjunct of the element $(\lambda \delta_{j i} - a_{j i})$ in $\Delta(\lambda)$.

**The question.** Is it possible to bound $b_{i j}(r)$ using values of matrix $A$? (At least for some $i$, $j$?)